# JOptionPane to return string

Tags: java, string, user-interface, joptionpane

I have a delete method in my program that I can't get working.

Basically I have an array that is used to write the array to a text file. This text file can then be read again.

To cancel a booking a `JOptionPane` appears asking the user to enter the `RoomID`.

Once this user has done this it should return the string for the `roomID` and all relevant details back into a `JOptionPane` (I had a return statement into a text area and my program found and returned the correct information).

My GUI class calls all my methods from a `listBookings` class.

```
public String deleteBooking(String roomID)
{
    int index = 0;
    for ( Booking s : bookings )
    {
        if ( s.getRoomID().equals(roomID))
        {
            int r = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog,null("Are you sure you would like to delete the following \n"
            + "deleteMessage",
            "Delete a booking",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,null,null);

            if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                bookings.remove(index);
            }
            if (r == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                return "Booking Was Not Canceled";
            }
        }
        index++;
    }
    return  "  Cannot find room";
```

new error message `<indentifier>` expected

Answer (score 0):

Try using the static method (I can't be sure if this is the correct syntax):

```
int r = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog("Are you sure you would like to delete the following \n"
        + "deleteMessage",
        "Delete a booking",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // do delete action
}
```

Comment: I wasnt sure about the static method because i thought that it ment i was unable to pass variables through? Tested that bit of code you gave me and i get pritty much the same error message i will try making the methoid static thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ahhhh... Forgot. At the end of the if statement (assuming the user says no), add in  } else { return ""; }

Comment: When making my method static BlueJ says i am unable to do this as its a non static method using non static variables :(

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to make the method static, just make a static call to JOptionPane (as my example shows). Also, in the parameter list, add in three nulls to the end and one to be the first parameter, like this: int r = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you sure you would like to delete the following \n"
        + "deleteMessage",
        "Delete a booking",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, null, null);

if (r == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // do delete action
}

Comment: At the end of the OptionPane call i.e. [...] JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null, null, null);

Comment: Looked through my code againt JOptionPane Examples and do not understand why i would get the error <identifier> expected